# Why is there no record of deleted answers on ASE?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that an answer was deleted from a question that I commented on ([Why would a flight from North America to Asia sometimes fly over the Atlantic?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53972/3212), the deleted answer had some reference to Riemann geometry).

On Math SE (which I am more familiar with) many answers get deleted, but the
answer (and usually most of the non offensive comments) remain (for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2871309/27978).

Why is this? It would seem useful to see deleted answers (unless they contain objectionable content, of course).

Comment: Apart from the answer you already got, it is generally not useful to see the deleted answers, otherwise they would not get deleted in the first place. Only users with extended moderation tool access can see them, because they need it to use those tools.

Comment: I find useful on MSE as I mentioned albeit the nature of MSE is different to ASE

Comment: that makes me wonder about why on MSE useful answers get deleted. Here we delete answers that are not useful.

Comment: On MSE it shows other approaches to solutions that did not pan out.

Comment: that's my point. they are useful and should not be deleted.

Comment: I believe they are typically deleted by the poster rather than a moderator. Certainly I have deleted answers when I realised I had made an egregious error in reading or answering. In any event, @Jamiec's answer explains my confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On mathematics.se you have enough rep to see deleted answers.  Here you have not built up enough to do so.

See [privileges](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Never occurred to me. Much appreciated.